# Expectations of the Wiener Process

Tags: expected-value, brownian-motion, variance

In the Wiener process, by definition, we have that $E(W(t))=0$.
What would be the $E(W(e^{2t})$?

My best guess would be that this would equal to 0 again because the expectation with the Wiener process of any t would be equal to 0.

Furthermore, what would be the variance of this Wiener Process?

Comment: Yes, the expectation is zero for all $t$ and so $E(W(e^{2t})=0$. Regarding the variance: What do you mean by "this" Wiener process? A (one-dimensional) Wiener process has variance $t$, by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since for any $s\ge0$ we have that $W(s) = W(s)-W(0)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,s)$, we have $W(e^{2t})\sim\mathcal{N}(0,e^{2t})$, with mean $0$ and variance $e^{2t}$.

It is *not* a Wiener process as it has the wrong variance.